# retain unique values in txt file with counts

Tags: text-processing

I have a text file with a single word in each line. I would like to convert this to a text file that only has each word appearing once, and also give the number of times that word appeared in the original file.

Is there a simple unix command (or set of commands) that do this?

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
sort file1 | uniq -c > file2
```